# Getting String Value when delimiter exists vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am working on finishing up a mvc 3 vb.net app... I have to parse about 2000 entries in a database and get the string value to the right of a " : " delimiter from one of the columns... Everything to the left I am not worried about but I need the value that is to the right of the colon for that item.. I have more issues involving needing to select string characters to the right or left of a delimiter... But if someone can show me how to achieve the above I can figure out the rest from there... Thanks again...

a example of the string is Jackson Smokehouse Fish Food:John Jacob JinggleHimer Schmit
I would want to eliminate the first part of the string or just select the second part and put it in a variable for later processing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string.Split(':') which will split your string into a string array.  so you can just grab the string to the right.  My VB is rusty:

```
Dim stringToRight as String
stringToRight = databaseString.Split("1"c)(1)
```

There are probably better ways, but this is straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... So to make sure I got this... Say I

Comment: Ok lastly what is the ("1"c)(1) saying?

Comment: @Skindeep2366 `"1"c` is a character in VB.NET, so we are calling `Split` and passing it that character as a parameter. Split returns an array. The `(1)` is used to index into the array, getting the string at position 1 (2nd item since it starts at zero).

Comment: In VB - you should be able to just call .Split(":"), no need to declare it as a character.  @SkinDeep - this will work just fine 'as long as you do not have a colon anywhere else in the strings that you are splitting.'  If you do - you are going to have to create a more elegant solution.